# How to extend a background to scale entire page [HTML]

Tags: html

Alright, I'm trying to make my background image extend across the width of the entire screen, and same with the white background below it.  Can someone tell me the easiest way of making this possible?  Here's my site:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20517056/jimedit2.html
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20517056/jimedit2.css

Here is the CSS:

I basically just want the blue background to extend across the whole page, and the white background below it to extend with it as well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#lightblue {
    background: url(jimedit2media/lightblue.gif); /* remove the no-repeat */
    visibility: visible;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 0; /* set z-index to 0 */
    width: 100%; /* change this to 100% */
    height: 100%; /* change this to 100% */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but something I noticed is that this only works when it is a 'fixed' background.  Is there anyway to make it absolute while still maintaining that background?  I didn't want it be the entire page's background, just the background for the 'top' portion.

Comment: You can set the height to be the same as the top portion, or you can restructure your divs to be align horizontally. (ie: #main > #top , #middle)

Comment: That's what I did, thanks, but it still doesn't allow me to scroll without it being 'fixed' as opposed to 'absolute' any ideas?

Comment: Changing it to absolute as I said above seems to work fine here (using chrome). Can you better illustrate your issue? I think I may not be getting exactly what you want to do.

Comment: When I change it to absolute, it doesn't expand the width to 100% any more, any ideas on this?  Or should I upload again?